# ValueError: objects are not aligned

Tags: python, numpy

Why does this code

```
def fun(t1,t):
    v = np.array([t,t1])
    M = np.matrix([[0,0],[0,0]])
    a = np.dot(scipy.linalg.expm(M, q=0),v)
    return a[0] 
x =  np.linspace(0,10,201)
y = np.linspace(10,0,201)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y) 
im = pl.imshow(fun(X,Y),cmap=cm.RdBu)
show()
```

give me the error "ValueError: objects are not aligned"?
I tried to write my vector as `v= np.array([[t],[t1]])` but that didn't help either. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: On which line you get this error?

Comment: Tell us the line, and the shapes of the offending objects.

Comment: the error is at line   `a = np.dot(sp.linalg.expm(M, q=0),v)`

ValueError: shapes (2,2) and (2,201,201) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 201 (dim 1)

Comment: `np.dot` uses the last dim of the 1st arg, and **2nd to the last** of the 2nd.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like here

```
a = np.dot(scipy.linalg.expm(M1, q=0),v)
```

you trying to take the dot product between two arrays with incompatible sizes.
Before this line

```
a = np.dot(scipy.linalg.expm(M1, q=0),v)
```

variable `v` has size

```
v.shape
Out[16]: (2, 201, 201)
```

matrix `M`

```
M.shape
Out[18]: (2, 2)
```

Also, you use undefined variable `M1` in `np.dot` line.

Comment: Thanks, M1 should be M indeed. How can I define my vector such that it is just (2,1)?

Comment: @Odile SmitsSo I can answer your question please tell me what you trying to do In this lines `x =  np.linspace(0,10,201)
y = np.linspace(10,0,201)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)`?

Comment: I just defined a grid op points. Could as well be something like: `x = arange(-3.0,3.0,0.1), y = arange(-3.0,3.0,0.1)` Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Odile Smits  What result you want to get multiplying matrix of points by matrix?

Comment: This is a simplfied function of what I actually want to calculate. My function looks something like this:  `W = e^{M*t} . v(tau,t)` where M is a time independent matrix, and the vector v is dependent on two variables. So what I expect to get from the dot product of the exponent and the vector v, is a vector W. The first component of this vector W(tau,t) is what I want to make a 2d plot of.

Answer (score 1):

To overcome the error I rewrote the code as:

```
def corrm(t1,t):
   v = np.array([t1,t])
   M = np.matrix([[0,0],[0,0]])
   a = np.dot(sw.expm(M, q=0),v) 
   return a[0]

points = 50
k = []
x = np.linspace(-3.0,3.0,points)
y = np.linspace(-3.0,3.0,points)
for i in x:
    for j in y:
        k.append([corrm(i,j)])
k = np.reshape(k,(points,points))
X,Y = meshgrid(x, y) # grid of point
imshow(k,cmap=cm.RdBu)

show()
```

It works now!
Thanks for the help guys.